# Payment using credit card through balanced payment in rails step by step

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, api, balanced-payments

I am new to use `balanced payments.`

After get credit card info what is first, second... all steps..

can any one give me `step by step` so i can do on that way.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

The steps would depend on what type of application you're trying to develop.

The basis of the system is that you create a Customer for each of your users. balanced.js removes the need for you to be PCI compliant because the sensitive data is submitted directly to Balanced and never goes through your servers. You use balanced.js to tokenize credit cards and bank accounts and add them to specific Customer instances. Once you've got the cards and bank accounts added you can do things like debit customerBuyerA and credit customerSellerB.

Next, I encourage you to read through some of the common fee scenarios to get an idea of what's going to work well for your business. https://docs.balancedpayments.com/current/#collecting-your-fees

Both https://docs.balancedpayments.com/current/overview.html and https://docs.balancedpayments.com/current/api.html have plenty of information to get you going from there.

I encourage you to stop by #balanced on IRC to get any other development questions answered.

Comment: Thanks for answer.. i want to submit user credits card info and pay bill (EX:$20) to owner only and not to save any card info.. so can u suggest me steps?

Answer (score 0):

I solved using below code in test mode (in `RUBY`):

1. `Install gem "balanced"`
2. Assign API key

   `Balanced.configure('API KEY')`
3. Accept user card info

   `card = Balanced::Card.new(  :card_number => "4111111111111111",
                               :expiration_month => "12",
                               :expiration_year => "2020"
                             ).save`
4. Create buyer to debit fee

`buyer = Balanced::Marketplace.my_marketplace.create_buyer(:card_uri => card.uri)`

5  Debit from buyer account

```
`another_debit = buyer.debit(
        :amount => 1000,
        :appears_on_statement_as => "MARKETPLACE.COM"
    )`
```

7 Credit to Merchant account (You need to verify Bank account first from [here](https://docs.balancedpayments.com/current/api.html?language=ruby#verifying-a-bank-account))

```
merchant = Balanced::Account.find('/v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP6wn7oEW117Yn9gKXuQaTIO/bank_accounts/BANK ACC ID')
    merchant.credit('1000')
```

Hope work for any one and suggestion welcome.